# Difference between Zorn's Lemma and the ascending chain condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $S$ be a non-empty partially ordered set with respect to a relation $\leq$. Then:

> Zorn's Lemma: If $S$ has the property that any totally ordered subset $U\subset S$ has an upper bound, then $S$ has a maximal element
>
> Ascending Chain Condition: Every strictly increasing chain eventually stabilises.

The a.c.c implies that **every** subset of $S$ has a maximal element and we can also deduce the same from Zorn's Lemma, so what, if any, is the difference between the two? I feel like they are both saying the same thing

Answer (score 6):

This is much weaker.

Consider the natural numbers, with an added maximal point which we shall call $\infty$. This partial order satisfies Zorn's lemma, every chain has an upper bound, indeed $\infty$ itself is an upper bound (it's a maximum element!) of any chain.

But the chain $\Bbb N$ is strictly increasing and does not stabilize. So this linear order does not satisfy the ascending chain condition.

The two statements are very close, and for a good reason. Stating that "*the ascending chain condition implies the existence of maximal elements*" is equivalent to stating Zorn's lemma when the chains are finite. Namely, "*if every chain is finite then there exists a maximal element*". This is also equivalent to the *Principle of Dependent Choice* which is a weak version of the axiom of choice (although strong enough to prove countable choice).